# Removing NaN rows from imported .csv file

Tags: r, csv, nan

I have found several solutions to this issue, but have not been able to get it to work on my end. I imported a .csv file with 77,728 objects of 3 variables. 2 of the 3 variables have NaN values assigned to them. I tried to remove them with this:

```
str = T1310_temp
T1310_temp <- na.omit(T1310_temp)
View(T1310_temp)
```

Running the view command just returned the initial dataset I imported, with no errors. I'm very new to coding so I'm fairly sure it's a small mistake. I'm coding in the latest version of RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NoNaN <- T1310_temp[!is.na(T1310_temp)]
```

Example:

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, NaN)
x1
1   2 NaN
x2 <- x1[!is.na(x1)]
x2
1 2
```

If T1310_temp is a data.frame you can process all of the columns using lapply:

```
NoNaN <- lapply(T1310_temp, function(x) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
```

NoNaN will be a list of the 3 column vectors of the data frame.

Comment: It removed the two other columns, but did not get rid of the NaN values

Comment: Is T1310_temp a matrix, dataframe or vector?  See my example for a vector in the edited Answer 1